# 16.04 alongside win10 installation from USBstick

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, usb

I shrinked Win partitions making room for ubuntu - an unallocated partition, Downloaded .iso image, image copied to USBstick and booted from USB.
Chose install ubuntu, followed the instructions, but never got to the question regarding dual boot (which is mentioned inall assisting manuals) .
Bootable USBstick is identified as /dev/sda,
seems that stick booted OS does not identify the hard disk.
I guess that I have to define hard disk unallocated partition so that it is identified by stick booted OS. Any ideas?

Comment: Please help us helping you. Boot from your USB-stick, choose `Try Ubuntu without installing`.  After Ubuntu loaded open terminal with `Ctrl+Alt+T`. Then type `sudo parted -l`and hit `Enter`. Copy the output and paste it into your question.

Answer (score 0):

To dual boot your machine..ubuntu needs some unallocated memory.
For that open disk management select any big disk and right click select option>shrink volume...type 70000mb(thats enough to run smoothly) and hit enter..u will get a black area as unallocated..now make bootable pendrive of Ubuntu shut down ur system boot ur pendrive using boot key and select usb select install ubuntu, going further u will get an option >install ubuntu alongside windows click it and go ahead..this should install ubuntu on your system (make sure both of them are in UEFI mode or one which your machine is running on(check in BIOS menu)) if it doesn't appear then choose "something else"option and you will have to manually partition unallocated (sample images attached here)
[image]
[image: i will prefer install alongside if u wish to do it manually do these]
[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

HERE I HAVE NOT CREATED SWAP AREA IF IT ASKS U TO GIVE SOME SWAP AREA THEN ALLOCATE 2X RAM OF YOUR MACHINE 
Continue installation...reboot after completion.. hope this helps :)

Comment: The twice the RAM "rule" is quite outdated. Modern systems with lots of RAM may never use swap but if you want to have some then ~2GB is more than enough. Make just a little more than the total RAM if you intend to use hibernation (perhaps you should avoid it), and that's it.

Comment: Ya thats why i dint include swap area in answer.. since i don't do it..but sometimes it asks that u dint create swap area...so for better performance i thought 2x is better.. anyways thankx for info :)

Comment: Why would adding space that won't be used anyway increase performance?

Comment: Windows 10 default is in hibernation when shut down...won't it be needed :/ please clear my doubt about swap area..:/

Comment: I really don't know what Windows 10 and its default behavior has something to do with it Linux swap??? Apparently you don't know what swap is for. Here's a hint: It does the some job the file pagefile in the main Windows partition does, extend memory with the trade-off of slowliness (swap or pagefile reside on an drive **slower** than RAM).

Comment: @Moti consider accepting as solution by clicking checkmark just below downvote symbol (if it helps) :) so as to encourage me n other people to answer more.

Comment: It did not work for me.

Comment: The installation did not show the option to install alongside. It seems to me that the oS does not see the hard disk

Comment: For that option both must be in UEFI mode or both must be in LEGACY mode

Comment: The stick was configured for UEFI, using rufus. It seems that the stick loaded ubuntu does not see the hard disk or its partitions. Is it possible that some drivers are missing? Should I try an older version of ubuntu?

Comment: Try using UUI...www.pendrivelinux.com..u just have to put iso and make bootable.. Rufus Is little buggy..i wonder how it is not locating ur hdd! Do u get free. Space in something else option?

Comment: Hi, I finally got to the root of the problem. My hw is a Lenovo Yoga 900 laptop. Surprisingly it does not support Linux. See http://www.theregister.co.uk/2016/09/21/lenovo_denies_plot_with_microsoft_to_block_linux_installs/. Thanks to all who tried to help. I diverted to an asus system and all went fine.

Comment: Haha ...gud!..gud luck